Is it normal to see state change to inactive, and back to resume in flutter apps
I have a mobile application build with flutter, that sends some strange analytics events. Notably I see state_change to inactive, and resume again.
I couldn't reproduce it locally on multiple device, neither I could see any glitch while I was testing on browserstack.
Is this a real problem you think? Does anyone has a clue of why this might be happening, like a memory problem? or how to troubleshoot it?
